# Declaring an async function in an existing object

Tags: javascript, function, ecmascript-6, async-await, syntax-error

Here is what I have already:

```
myFunct({ myObj: { db } })
```

I need to add another function in such as:

```
myFunct({ myObj: async ({ req }) => {
  //more scripts
} })
```

What I tried and failed:

```
myFunct({ myObj: {
  db,
  async (req) => {
    //more scripts
  }
} })
```

At the => I get the syntax error:

```
Unexpected token, expected {
```

Comment: It's not working since you are not naming the property that will hold the function. The `{ db }` syntax is a shorthand to declare properties with the same name as the identifier is used as value, e.g.: `{ db: db }`.

Comment: I knew it would be something I was easily overlooking. Trying to switch my programming language from php to node has came with its own set of challenges.

Answer (score 3):

You have to supply a property name.

If you have a variable, it can act as both the property name and value.

```
const myFunction = async (req) => {
    //more scripts
};

myFunct({ myObj: {
  db,
  myFunction
} })
```

If you only have a value, then you need to state the property name explicitly.

```
myFunct({ myObj: {
  db,
  myFunction: async (req) => {
    //more scripts
  }
} })
```

Comment: Or alternatively to the second example, `async myFunction (req) { ... }`, though `this` will behave differently.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts how so differently? Being new to async-await, can you direct me to some explanation?

Comment: @amaster — https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable

Answer (score 3):

You did not give a key to your function :

Try :

```
myFunct({
  myObj: {
    db,
    yourKey: async (req) => {
      //more scripts
    }
  }
})
```